# How can I dynamically declare a variable type then use it as an argument when instantiating a custom view in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, swiftui

**What I'm doing:**

I'm making a reusable `tableView` and have just about finished, but I'm unable to reference properties in my view model because I have declared my model type as `AnyObject` inside the table view struct.

I want to dynamically declare the variable type when instantiating the `tableView`.

**For example, this is how I use my custom table view:**

```
struct MyView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var myViewModel: MyViewModel

    var body: some View {

        return

          CustomTableView(model: myViewModel as MyViewModel)
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have to declare the type in my view because I'm using the `AnyObject` type in my table view struct. This is because the model will vary depending on where I'm using the custom table view, and so I need the flexibility.

**This is my table view Struct:**

```
struct CustomTableView: UIViewRepresentable {

    var model: AnyObject
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

        var customTableView: CustomTableView
        let cellIdentifier = "MyCell"

        init(_ customTableView: customTableView) {
            self.customTableView = customTableView
        }

        func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return 7
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
            return cell
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> DabbleTableView.Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITableView {  
        let cellIdentifier = "MyCell"
        let tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.delegate = context.coordinator
        tableView.dataSource = context.coordinator
        tableView.register(MyTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
        tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCell.SeparatorStyle.none
        return tableView    
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiViewController: UITableView, context: Context) {           
    }
}
```

**What I want to do:**

Either have the table view automatically use the `ViewModel` type name declared when instantiating the table view, or pass in the correct `ViewModel` type when instantiating the table view.

It's not clear to me how this could be done. I was thinking type alias might work, but the more I read into it, the more I realised it wasn't the right solution.

Passing in the type as a string doesn't work because Swift will recognise the argument as a string.

What would be the cleanest way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The possible approach is to use generics (conforming also to any custom protocol if/when needed), so you don't need to cast types and use it as

```
struct MyView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var myViewModel: MyViewModel

    var body: some View {
        CustomTableView(model: myViewModel)
    }
}
```

so `CustomTableView` should be declared as

```
struct CustomTableView<Model:ObservableObject>: UIViewRepresentable {

    var model: Model

    ...
```

Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

**Update:** below is compilable example

```
// base protocol for CustomTableView model
protocol CustomTableViewModel {
    func numberOfSections() -> Int
    func numberOfRows(in section: Int) -> Int
}

// some specific model
class MyViewModel: ObservableObject, CustomTableViewModel {
    func numberOfSections() -> Int { 1 }
    func numberOfRows(in section: Int) -> Int { 7 }
}

// usage
struct MyView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var myViewModel: MyViewModel

    var body: some View {
        CustomTableView(model: myViewModel)
    }
}

// generic table view
struct CustomTableView<Model:ObservableObject & CustomTableViewModel>: UIViewRepresentable {

    var model: Model

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

        var customTableView: CustomTableView
        let cellIdentifier = "MyCell"

        init(_ customTableView: CustomTableView) {
            self.customTableView = customTableView
        }

        func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            customTableView.model.numberOfSections()
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            customTableView.model.numberOfRows(in: section)
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
            return cell
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITableView {
        let cellIdentifier = "MyCell"
        let tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.delegate = context.coordinator
        tableView.dataSource = context.coordinator
        tableView.register(MyTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
        tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCell.SeparatorStyle.none
        return tableView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiViewController: UITableView, context: Context) {
    }
}

class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell { }
```

Comment: Hi, this partially works. But I'm still unable to reference a properties and functions in my view model. For example, in the numberOfRowsInSection delegate method, I did this self.customTableView.model.nameOfFunction() and I'm still unable to access the function. I have about 5 different ViewModels that I will use with this table view. The Model name declared in table view can't be static. It needs to be able to work with any view model I use with the table view. I should be able to access properties and functions inside the model used, and shouldn't need to manually edit the tableview file

Comment: @LondonGuy, yes, I shown common direction. You need to create custom protocol, common for the expected models, and add it to generics.

Comment: Could you give me a basic example of how your view model would look with the custom protocol? I can do further research after.

Comment: @LondonGuy, see Update section